# Sublime Text2 class variables hint php

Tags: php, ide, editor, sublimetext

Hi guys does anyone know how I can make it so SublimeText2 will suggest class variables and functions for me in a php file - similar to eclipse and aptana?

Ie when I type `$this->` I get a popup of accessible properties. Right now it gives me a list of everything.

Thanks guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

checkout this plugin, you need a package manager to install it

https://github.com/Kronuz/SublimeCodeIntel

Comment: Hm I have this but I'm still getting all these unhelpful hints - I want it to be more specific like Eclipse and give me class variables and functions ONLY when I use $this inside a class. 
Any clues?